# [Xcode][Swift] I can't solve this error. I use readLine() into input value. Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift:580: Fatal error: Index out of range

Tags: ios, swift

input value =>

15
push 1
push 2
front
back
size
empty
pop
pop
pop
size
empty
pop
push 3
empty
front

I used readLine() and split. but when input value split substring,
This error occurs. "Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift:580: Fatal error: Index out of range "
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jmiX.png
and this is my source. and I want to know the best way to get the user's value as input.

```
import Foundation
public struct Queue{
    private var data = [Int]()
    mutating func enqueue(element: Int){
        data.append(element)
    }
    mutating func dequeue(){
        isEmpty == false ? print("\(data.removeFirst())") : print("-1")
    }
    var size :Int {
        data.count
    }
    var isEmpty: Bool{
        data.count >= 1 ? false : true
    }
    var front: Int{
        guard let element = data.first else{
            return -1
        }
        return element
    }
    var back: Int{
        guard let element = data.last else{
            return -1
        }
        return element
    }
}
let input = readLine()!
var queue = Queue()
for _ in 0 ..< Int(input)! {
    let command = readLine()!.split(separator: " ")
    switch command[0]{
    case "push":
        queue.enqueue(element: Int(command[1])!)
    case "pop":
        queue.dequeue()
    case "size":
        print("\(queue.size)")
    case "empty":
        queue.isEmpty == true ? print("1") : print("0")
    case "front":
        print("\(queue.front)")
    case "back":
        print("\(queue.back)")
    default:
        break;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Whenever you write ! In swift you should think “is there a better way to do this?”. Overall you need to be more defensive in your programming and check values and variables before using them, for example you need to check that the array contains at least two items before doing `command[1]`.

Comment: Oh, so that's why I got the error message. thank you for telling me.